# Writing conditional statement for META Robot tag in BlogSpot

Tags: conditional-statements, blogger

I am trying to write conditional statement in Blogspot template, which add `<meta content='index,follow' name='robots'/>` on given Page url and add `<meta content='noindex,follow' name='robots'/>` to any other pages. Here is the statement..it is not working.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>

   <b:if cond='data:blog.url == "http://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/privacy-policy.html"'>
    <meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow"/></b:if> 


  <b:if cond='data:blog.url == "http://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/privacy-policy.html"'>
    <meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow"/></b:if> 


  <b:if cond='data:blog.url == "http://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/privacy-policy.html"'>
    <meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow"/></b:if> 

<b:else/>
<meta content='noindex,follow' name='robots'/>
</b:if>
```

Please help..this code is not working.

Comment: why you do that in the template? you can do that in the pages itself on the options on the side.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `data:blog.url`, whose equality you checked, returns a value that starts with `https`. The condition is never true since you are comparing with the address string starting with `http`.

| register | value |
| --- | --- |
| data:blog.canonicalUrl | http:// yourblog.blogspot.com/p/about.html |
| data:blog.url | https:// yourblog.blogspot.com/p/about.html |

If your blog site uses https, use the data:blog.url variable:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
    <!-- this is a page -->
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;https://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/about.html&quot;'>
        <!-- about page -->
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;https://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/contact.html&quot;'>
        <!-- contact page -->
    </b:if>
<b:else/>
    <!-- this is not a page -->
</b:if>
```

or if your blog site uses http, use the data:blog.canonicalUrl variable:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
    <!-- this is a page -->
    <b:if cond='data:blog.canonicalUrl == &quot;http://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/about.html&quot;'>
        <!-- about page http -->
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.canonicalUrl == &quot;http://yourblog.blogspot.com/p/contact.html&quot;'>
        <!-- contact page http -->
    </b:if>
<b:else/>
    <!-- this is not a page http -->
</b:if>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what was changed, and what was wrong with the code in the question? This will increase the value of your answer to the asker and future visitors.